# subprocess.CalledProcessError: what *is* the error?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

cmd = "grep -r * | grep jquery"
print cmd

subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

**subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'grep -r * | grep jquery' returned non-zero exit status 1**

I can execute that command in my shell without issues. How can I see the **actual** error in python?

*The snippet is part of a larger script which takes multiple arguments and chains the grep commands + adds some excludes (I don't need to grep log files or minified JavaScript. Hence the pedantic syntax.*

*Python 2.7.10*

Comment: That just means the command returned a non-zero exit code...which is exactly what `grep` does if your match fails.

Comment: aaah! no results you mean?

Comment: Maybe there is something I'm misunderstanding with your grep command, but are you looking for jquery within a path? Why not just `grep -r jquery .`?

Comment: BTW, `grep -r *` looks for the name of the first file in your directory inside all the other files in your directory. I can't conceive of under what circumstances that would be correct behavior.

Comment: thanks for clarifying! good that I asked :-) I've changed it to `grep -r jquery .`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"non-zero exit status" means that the *command you ran* indicated a status other than success. For `grep`, the documentation explicitly indicates that an exit status of 1 indicates no lines were found, whereas an exit status more than 1 indicates that some other error took place.

To quote the manual:

> **EXIT STATUS** - The grep utility exits with one of the following values:
>
> ```
> 0     One or more lines were selected.
> 1     No lines were selected.
> >1    An error occurred.
> ```

---

By the way -- if you want to look for the string `jquery` in all files under the current directory (recursively), use `grep -r jquery .`; `grep -r *` searches for *the name of the first file in your directory* inside *the contents of all other files in your directory*.

Answer (score 17):

[Quoting docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`. The
> `CalledProcessError` object will have the return code in the `returncode`
> attribute and any output in the `output` attribute.

```
import subprocess

cmd = "grep -r * | grep jquery"
print cmd

try:
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.returncode
    print e.output
```

Of error message was printed to stderr, you need keyword argument `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

There is no other source of 'what went wrong' besides return code and stdout / stderr.

Comment: `e.output` doesn't help in this case as it's empty (even with stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) but it might help in other situations. Thx.

Comment: There is no other source to retrieve that info. For simple tools, there is finite non-zero return codes with associated meanings. For complex tools parsing output is required (or exact error reason is ambiguous).

Comment: I had to use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.check_output`, with the additional parameters `check=True, capture_output=True`. Then the subprocess's error message was included in the error's `stderr` attribute.